# How to avoid null pointer exception in the below code? And Would read() function print a string in the code below?

Tags: java, stream, inputstream

For the code below compiler gives a null pointer exception when using the read function. I want to display, whatever the user types, on the screen.
Secondly the read function returns an int, but I want to display the string that user types, Would this display the string or is this any method that I would have to use to display the String?

```
//This part is in the main method.
InputStream obj=new Task(t);
int c;
    try {
        while((c=obj.read())!=-1){
            System.out.print(""+c);
        }

//This one is another class.

class Task extends InputStream{
byte[] content;
int num=0;
public Task(JTextField t){
    t.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            if(e.getKeyCode()==e.VK_ENTER){
                content=t.getText().getBytes();
                t.setText("");
            }
            super.keyPressed(e);
        }
    });

}
public int read(){
    if(num>=content.length){
        return -1;
    }
    else return content[num++];
}}
```

Comment: Do you really mean that the *compiler* gives a null pointer exception?

Comment: What's a compiler? (not relevant to the question, but informative wrt semantics) http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/compiler

Comment: I'm using netbeans IDE, can u please answer the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`content` is initialized only when this block executes:

```
if(e.getKeyCode()==e.VK_ENTER){
    content=t.getText().getBytes();
    t.setText("");
}
```

To go around this, you could add a check in your `read` method: `if(content == null) return -1;`

EDIT:

When you override a method, you should use the `@Override` directive. Your current method, with the addition of the null check, adheres to the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()). If you want to get the string value, you will need to add some other functionality.

```
public String GetContent() { 
    if(content == null)
        return ""; 
    return new String(content);
}
```

However, the above will depend on how you intend to use task. Another option would be something of the sort:

```
public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) {
    if(b == null) return -1;

    //Use System.Arraycopy to copy `content` within `b`.
}
```

Comment: I got the first point but couldn't get how to convert to String

Comment: @BilalRafique: One of the string constructors allows you to pass in a byte array, which is something you have. I'll update my answer shortly.

Comment: @Danielson: The above read method u gave cannot work. Because the read method I'm using is an abstract method which I have to define plus I can't check the end of file in case of this String method.

Comment: @BilalRafique, uhm... It's not my answer... It's my edit, but only cosmetically, I think you should answer npinti...